# Solving an equation with the sum of inverse cosine and inverse tangent

Tags: trigonometry

I have the below question and have to find value of $x$.
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right) = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

I took $x$ as $\tan y$ but it isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

let $x = \cot t = \frac{\cos t }{\sin t}.$ then $$\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t - 1}{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t + 1}=\cos(2t),\\
 \frac{2x}{x^2 - 1} = \frac{2\cos t/\sin t }{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t - 1} = \tan 2t$$

now we have $$\begin{align}2\pi/3 &= \cos^{-1}(\cos(2t)) + \tan^{-1}(\tan 2t)\\
&= (2t + 2k\pi) + (2t + m\pi)  \\&= (2t) + (2t), (2t) + (2t-\pi)\\
&=4t, 4t-\pi, \cdots \end{align}$$

therefore we get $$t = \pi/6, 5\pi/12, \cdots\\x = \sqrt 3, 2 - \sqrt 3$$

Comment: You last number is $2-\sqrt 3$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, You are right? But, is that the only solution?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. For sure, there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, How can be there be an infinite number of solutions?According to my  answer, there are exactly two solutions, $x=\tan\dfrac\pi{12},\tan\dfrac\pi3$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. You are right and I am stupid ! I made a mistake on my side. I am sorry. Cheers :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks. edited now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
 take $x=\tan(\frac{t}{2})$ and solve the problem for $t$ then solve the problem for $x$ use the following:
$$\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\arctan(\tan(t)),\arccos\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)=\arccos(\cos(t)) $$

Comment: you were not correct about the comment you left on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the definitions of cosine and tangent to find the three sides of the triangle that each term describes.  What do you find, say, the sine of the angle for each term to be in terms of $ \ x \ $ ?  The angle for each term is then the arcsine of that ratio.  If you take the sine of both sides of the resulting equation, you will have a quadratic equation to solve.

[This equation is an example of using mathematical identities to turn a simple expression into something that looks intimidating.]

**EDIT --** Now that **abel** has posted answers, I will describe the method I proposed above.

If we look at the angles described by the inverse trigonometric functions in the equations and treat the expressions in the ratios as the legs of right triangles, both describe a triangle with legs $ \ x^2 \ - \ 1 \ \ , \ \ 2x \  \ , \ \ x^2 \ + \ 1 \ $ .  *Both* terms can then be written as $ \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{2x}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \right) $ , so we obtain

$$ 2 \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{2x}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \right)  \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{2x}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \ = \ \sin \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \ \ \sqrt{3} \ x^2 \ - \ 4x \ + \ \sqrt{3} \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

which has the solutions  $ \ x \ = \ \frac{4 \ \pm \ 2}{2 \ \sqrt{3}} \ $ .  The solution $ \ \frac{6}{2 \ \sqrt{3}} \ = \ \sqrt{3} \ $ works in the original equation, both terms thus being the angle $ \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ $ ; the other solution, $ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ $ is spurious.

After I saw **abel**'s result, I realized I'd been a bit precipitate: the solution I just gave requires the angle to be in the first quadrant, where sine, cosine, and tangent are all positive:  this is the  $ x^2 \ > \ 1 \ $ case.  I had neglected the possibility that $ \ x^2 \ < \ 1 \ $ , which puts the arccosine term in Quadrant II and the arctangent term in Quadrant IV.

Here, it is better to express both terms using arccosine.  The arctangent term must now be written as $ \ \cos^{-1}  \left( \ \frac{x^2 \ - \ 1}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \ \right) \ - \ \pi \ $ .  Our equation becomes

$$  \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 \ + \ 1}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \right) \ + \ \cos^{-1}  \left( \ \frac{x^2 \ - \ 1}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \ \right) \ - \ \pi \ \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ 2 \ \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 \ - \ 1}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \right) \ \ = \ \frac{5 \pi}{3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{x^2 \ - \ 1}{x^2 \ + \ 1} \ = \ \sin \ \frac{5  \pi}{6} \ = \ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  x^2 \ - \ 1 \  \ = \ \ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ x^2 \  - \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (2 \ + \ \sqrt{3}  ) \ x^2 \  = \ 2 \ - \ \sqrt{3}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ = \ \frac{2 \ - \ \sqrt{3}}{2 \ + \ \sqrt{3} } \ = \ \ (2 \ - \ \sqrt{3})^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \pm ( 2 \ - \ \sqrt{3} )\ \ . $$

The negative value is spurious for the original equation, so the other solution is $ \ 2 \ - \ \sqrt{3} \ $ , corresponding to the angle terms $ \ \frac{5 \pi}{6} \ $ and $ \ - \frac{\pi}{6} \ $ .

Answer (score 0):

Like @abel,

let $\arccos\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=2y\implies\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=\cos2y$ and $0\le2y\le\pi$

Applying [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo), $x^2=\dfrac{1+\cos2y}{1-\cos2y}=\cot^2y$

As $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2,\cot y\ge0\implies\cot y=|x|$

$\implies y=\text{arccot}|x|=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan|x|\  \ \ \  (1)$

Similarly, let $\arctan\dfrac{2x}{x^2-1}=2u\implies\dfrac{2x}{x^2-1}=\tan2y=\dfrac{2\tan u}{1-\tan^2u}$ and $-\dfrac\pi2\le2u\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\tan u=-x,1/x$

**Case** $\#1:$

If $\tan u=-x,u=\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$

By $(1),$ if $x\ge0,$ $$2\left(\dfrac\pi2-\arctan x\right)+2\left(-\arctan x\right)=\dfrac{2\pi}3\iff\arctan x=\dfrac\pi{12}\implies x=\tan\dfrac\pi{12}$$

if $x<0,$ $$2\left(\dfrac\pi2+\arctan x\right)+2\left(-\arctan x\right)=\dfrac{2\pi}3\iff\pi=\dfrac{2\pi}3$$ which is impossible

**Case** $\#2:$

If $\tan u=1/x\iff x=\cot u\implies u=\text{arccot}(x)=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)$

Can you use $(1)$ like **Case** $\#1$